# Randomize my numbers in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: vb.net, random, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to Visual studio so.. I'm stuck.

I want to randomize between my numbers: `69, 119, 179`.
So when i press button1 it's gonna pick one of the 3 choices.
And then show it in Textbox1. Just as simple as that.

I found a randomize video on youtube that showed this code:

```
Dim rndnumber As Random
Dim number As Integer
rndnumber = New Random
number = rndnumber.Next(1, 1001)
TextBox1.Text = number.ToString
```

I thought that it was the right code for that but it wasn't.

Comment: Put them in an array, generate a number between 0 and 2 and `arry[rand_num]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Dim rndnumber As New Random
    Dim MyArray() As Integer = {69, 119, 179}

    TextBox1.Text = MyArray(rndnumber.Next(0, 3))
```